# Bandwidth and RAM for our VDS

Tags: bandwidth, memory, bandwidth-control, vds

We are planning give an iframe from our server to the site which daily visitor 500k. What do you think about how much do we need system resource such as bandwidth and RAM.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunatley it's not as easy as that. It all depends what's being run on the page / what webserver you're using etc. If it's only text, you really wont need much at all running ngix.

However if it's all dynamic content, it might need lots for mysql etc.

Can you go in to a bit more detail?

Comment: İframe contains the searchbox which has datepicker and city autocomplete. We are using all web borwser. We use a lotof mysql because autocomplete connect with mysql.

Comment: The answer is that given the information there is no answer. You'd have to test what the actual load is on the server because the application's architecture will determine how it uses resources. Even if you had numbers on how many users there are or what the database is that is used...if you have crap queries, it can tax the server more than if you have properly refined searches (for example.) Bottom line: YOU NEED TO LOAD TEST UNDER NEAR-ACTUAL USE CONDITIONS and get benchmarks.

Comment: ^ what he said ^

Comment: We use VDS With 2 GB RAM and 6GB/Montly. We trust our queries because this queries is not complex.if you are more information please write What i need for test my server or How can i do it.

Comment: Server's Physical Memory used  %99.  Swap %29